# BGI in updated wxDevCpp does not work

Tags: c++, bgi, winbgi

I need to use BGI graphics in my program and it worked just fine in the wxDevCpp 7.3. But now I installed an updated version of this IDE 7.4, did everything by instruction http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/, just like before, but now when I try to compile any simple program like

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main( )
{
    initwindow(400, 300, "First Sample");
    circle(100, 50, 40);
    while (!kbhit( ))
    {
        delay(200);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get multiple errors saying that

```
initwindow(), circle(), kbhit(), delay()
```

were not declared in the scope. I have no idea what to do.
The change in updated wxDevCpp is the different folder structure, but I copypasted the graphics.h and libbgi.a in several folders. I did not forget to add the linker commands just as the instruction said, but it does not work.
Also, I found another graphics.h which came along with installation of new wxDevCpp and though it might bring a conflict, so I just removed it. No change :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I solved it! It was actually trouble with the graphics.h
When I copypasted all the graphics.h into my .cpp, the compiler gave an error that int right was declared twice in the following code:

```
void printimage(
    const char* title=NULL, 
    double width_inches=7, double border_left_inches=0.75, double border_top_inches=0.75,
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );
```

redefinition of int right, so as it is just a prototype, I change it to:

```
void printimage(
    const char* title=NULL, 
    double width_inches=7, double border_left_inches=0.75, double border_top_inches=0.75,
    int left=0, int right=0, int=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );
```

Now it works!!!

Comment: I tried this but when I Compile & Run I got this error in `Makefile.wim`: _C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\Working\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status_ and it stops in this line :`$(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)`